# Generic way to save/restore variables in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.6

Is there an easy way to save/restore variables within a scope in Python 3?

For example:

```
x=4
with x=5:
   ... do something with x that's temporarily 5
```

or

```
with os.environ["FOO"] = "BAR":
   ... do something here
```

It seems like it would be super easy for the python interpreter to implement this (left hand side of assignment is saved, right hand side is executed on `__enter__`, restored on `__exit__`)

Or at least some library or whatever.

Doing this with temporary variables requires try/finally blocks, and is inherently unsafe and prone to runtime errors.  This seems "unpythonic" by comparison.

```
try:
    save = os.environ["FOO"]
    os.environ["FOO"] = "BAR"

   ... do something here

finally:
    os.environ["FOO"] = save
```

Comment: Why do it this way? It seems unpythonic and reduces code readability. Why not just use a temporary variable?

Comment: Why not a function…? That usually makes for more maintainable code anyway.

Comment: Answered both concerns above, and explained why the proposed syntax is far more "pythonic"... easier to read and not prone to bugs.   Also, a "function" is not available in many situations.  (ENV modification being canonical example, but there are lots of others!)

Comment: Looks like there might be a "patch.object" and "patch.dict" thingy that does this already built in to the python unit test library!

Answer (score 0):

[In response to this question, I made a library that does this.](https://gist.github.com/earonesty/977b14c93358fe9b9ee674baac5d42d7)  Not sure if there's an easier way to do it though.  Looks my library might be a clone of "patch.object" and "patch.dict" .... not sure.   Docs on those seem vague to me.

```py
import inspect, os, ctypes

class dicttemp:
    def __init__(self, obj, changes):
        self.obj = obj
        self.save = {}
        for var, val in changes.items():
            if var in obj:
                self.save[var] = obj[var]
            else:
                self.save[var] = None
            self.obj[var] = val

    def __enter__(self):
        pass

    def __exit__(self, type, val, trace):
        for var, val in self.save.items():
            if val is not None:
                self.obj[var] = val
            else:
                del self.obj[var]

class envtemp(dicttemp):
    def __init__(self, changes):
        super().__init__(os.environ, changes)

class vartemp:
    def __init__(self, changes):
        self.frame = inspect.stack()[1][0]
        self.f_locals = {}
        self.f_globals = {}
        for var, val in changes.items():
            if var in self.frame.f_locals:
                self.f_locals[var] = self.frame.f_locals[var]
                self.frame.f_locals[var] = val
            elif var in self.frame.f_globals:
                self.f_globals[var] = self.frame.f_globals[var]
                self.frame.f_globals[var] = val
            ctypes.pythonapi.PyFrame_LocalsToFast(ctypes.py_object(self.frame), ctypes.c_int(0))

    def __enter__(self):
        pass

    def __exit__(self, type, val, trace):
        for var, val in self.f_locals.items():
            self.frame.f_locals[var] = val
        for var, val in self.f_globals.items():
            self.frame.f_globals[var] = val
        ctypes.pythonapi.PyFrame_LocalsToFast(ctypes.py_object(self.frame), ctypes.c_int(0))

import unittest

_test_y=4
class TestVarLib(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_local(self):
        x=4
        with vartemp({'x':5}):
            self.assertEqual(x,5)
        self.assertEqual(x,4)

    def test_mixed(self):
        global _test_y
        x=4
        _test_y=4
        with vartemp({'x':5, '_test_y':5}):
            self.assertEqual(x,5)
            self.assertEqual(_test_y,5)
        self.assertEqual(x,4)
        self.assertEqual(_test_y,4)

    def test_env(self):
        os.environ['FOO'] = '4'
        with envtemp({'FOO':'5','BAR':'5'}):
            self.assertEqual(os.environ['FOO'],'5')
            self.assertEqual(os.environ['BAR'],'5')
        self.assertEqual(os.environ['FOO'],'4')
        self.assertTrue('BAR' not in os.environ)
```

For example:

```
import os
from varlib import vartemp, envtemp

x = 3
y = 4
print ("Before: x is", x, "y is", y)

with vartemp({'x':93,'y':94}):
    print ("In temp: x is", x, "y is", y)

print ("After: x is", x, "y is", y)

with envtemp({'foo':'bar'}):
    print(os.getenv('foo'))

print(os.getenv('foo'))
```

Output is here:

```
Before: x is 3 y is 4
In temp: x is 93 y is 94
After: x is 3 y is 4
bar
None
```